# cannot import name 'PredResults' from 'predict.models'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Here is the code from my Django app named 'predict' from the models' file.

```
from django.db import models

class PredResults(models.Model):

month = models.FloatField()
grade = models.FloatField()
score = models.FloatField()
bonus_score = models.FloatField()
classification = models.CharField(max_length=30)

def __str__(self):
    return self.classification
```

When I am running my project, it's giving me an error that:

```
 File "C:\django_project\predict\views.py", line 4, in <module>
from .models import PredResults
ImportError: cannot import name 'PredResults' from 'predict.models' 
(C:\django_project\predict\models.py)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: try like this `from predict.models import PredResults`

Comment: Still the same issue. :/

Comment: Try adding your app config to the Django settings installed apps.

Comment: Already done that.